# Class: Property Attributes

Tags: c#, oop, properties

I have created a custom Attribute.

```
public class DisplayAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public bool IsDisplay;
        public string DisplayName;

        public DisplayAttribute()
        {
            IsDisplay = true;
            DisplayName = string.Empty;
        }

        public DisplayAttribute(bool isDisplay)
        {
            IsDisplay = isDisplay;
            DisplayName = string.Empty;
        }

        public DisplayAttribute(string displayName)
        {
            IsDisplay = true;
            DisplayName = displayName;
        }

        public DisplayAttribute(bool isDisplay,string displayName)
        {
            IsDisplay = isDisplay;
            DisplayName = displayName;
        }
    }
```

My motive of creating this attribute was to restrict property to get listed when i fetches property list from a particular class

Here is my class

```
 public class tblContacts : Connection
    {
        [Display(false)]
        public int ContactId { get; set; }

        [Display(true,"Category Name")]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        [Display("First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }
```

but when i execute following statement

```
tblContacts obj=new tblContacts();
obj.GetType().GetProperties();
```

it fails to satisfy my motive

Comment: Have you any exception

Comment: The GetProperties method doesn't even know that your attribute exists so why would it know to look for your attribute and ignore that property?  There's nothing in your code that is going to tell GetProperties to ignore a method and nor can there ever be.  What you need to do is to add your own filter after calling GetProperties to discard the ones that you don't want.

Comment: Isnt there anyway with which i just have to add annotation to satisfy my motive

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me.See [System.Reflection.BindingFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Type myType = (typeof(tblContacts));
            PropertyInfo[] myPropertyInfo = myType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            Console.WriteLine("The number of public properties is {0}.", myPropertyInfo.Length);

            // Display the public properties.
            DisplayPropertyInfo(myPropertyInfo);

            // Get the nonpublic properties.
            PropertyInfo[] myPropertyInfo1 = myType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            Console.WriteLine("The number of protected properties is {0}.", myPropertyInfo1.Length);

            // Display all the nonpublic properties.
            DisplayPropertyInfo(myPropertyInfo1);
        }
        public static void DisplayPropertyInfo(PropertyInfo[] myPropertyInfo)
        {

            // Display information for all properties. 
            for (int i = 0; i < myPropertyInfo.Length; i++)
            {
                PropertyInfo myPropInfo = (PropertyInfo)myPropertyInfo[i];
                Console.WriteLine("The property name is {0}.", myPropInfo.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("The property type is {0}.", myPropInfo.PropertyType);
            }
        }
    }

    public class DisplayAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public bool IsDisplay;
        public string DisplayName;

        public DisplayAttribute()
        {
            IsDisplay = true;
            DisplayName = string.Empty;
        }

        public DisplayAttribute(bool isDisplay)
        {
            IsDisplay = isDisplay;
            DisplayName = string.Empty;
        }

        public DisplayAttribute(string displayName)
        {
            IsDisplay = true;
            DisplayName = displayName;
        }

        public DisplayAttribute(bool isDisplay, string displayName)
        {
            IsDisplay = isDisplay;
            DisplayName = displayName;
        }
    }
    public class tblContacts
    {
        [Display(false)]
        public int ContactId { get; set; }

        [Display(true, "Category Name")]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        [Display("First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
The number of public properties is 3.
The property name is ContactId.
The property type is System.Int32.
The property name is CategoryName.
The property type is System.String.
The property name is FirstName.
The property type is System.String.
The number of protected properties is 0.
```

Comment: All the properties will be public only. I have to filter display only few properties from them

Comment: Type.GetProperties Method (BindingFlags) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x(v=vs.110).aspx